# Php fpdf page orientation bug

Tags: php, fpdf

I have problem with fpdf page orientation. 
Part of my code:

```
        $pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
        $pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $pdf->AddPage('L','A3');
        $pdf->SetWidths(array(50,200,50,50,50));
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);

        if(!empty($ow)){
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
                    $pdf->Ln();
                    $pdf->Cell('50',7,'OPEN TASK OVERDUE');
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
                    $groupedTasks=[];
                    foreach ($ow as $w) {
                        $groupedTasks[$w['date_due']][] =$w;
                    }
                    foreach ($groupedTasks as $key=>$val) {
                        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
                        $pdf->SetFillColor(0,0,0);
                        $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
                        $pdf->Ln();
                        $pdf->Cell('50',6,$key." (Due Date)",'','','',true);$pdf->Ln();
                        $pdf->Ln();
                        $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
                        $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
                        $pdf->Cell(50,7,"Lead",1,0,'C',true);
                        $pdf->Cell(200,7,"Note",1,0,'C',true);
                        $pdf->Cell(50,7,"Task type",1,0,'C',true);
                        $pdf->Cell(50,7,"Due date",1,0,'C',true);
                        $pdf->Cell(50,7,"Assign to",1,0,'C',true);
                        $pdf->Ln();
                        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
                        foreach ($val as $value) {
                            $pdf->Row([iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $value['lead_name']),
                                    iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $value['content']),
                                    iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $value['task_type']),
                                    iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $value['date_due']),
                                    iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $value['assign_to'])]
                            );
                        }
                    }

                }
```

And my problem is that some page (3-4) is in A3 orientation and other set orientation in A4 and my table is broken. 
What problem can be? 
I set orientation such as: `$pdf->AddPage('L','A3');`

My screen:http://clip2net.com/s/3KetEPv

Hope you will help me.Thanks!

Comment: solved: `$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table('L','mm','A3');`

Comment: Please add the solution as answer to your own question (yes, you're allowed to do that :) ) so you can close the question!